# make release-static-win64 Error Forking Monero

Tags: cryptonote, monero-forks, build

I am trying to Fork Monero and create a custom coin using the following process:

1. Create build environment and building Monero from source - DONE & WORKING!
2. Forking Monero, making changes based upon the (out-of-date) CryptoNote guide combined with online research and building from source - ERROR

Can anyone recommend a more robust method to be able to change the right settings to Fork Monero? There seems to be a lot of guess work involved at the moment when changing the right variables based on the CryptoNote guide.

I have attempted to compare Forks on Github and see how an existing working Fork has changed Monero variables but am struggling to find the right Forks to compare and know which changes to use.

Comment: Why are you forking?

Comment: Forking to create a new currency for a startup.